# How to change the value of an array so that it can be output again

Tags: java

Other codes have been completed,

but I don't know how to make a code to change the id and re-print it at the end.

I think it change getId() to id2.

So I tried, but the result I wanted didn't come out.

How to change this Id? Or is there a problem other codes?

plz help

Comment: `getId()` is a method so you cannot change it. Your code asks the user for an ID and then prints the corresponding Member object. But then, I guess, you want to change something. Not sure what. But whatever it is you just need to use a setter.

Comment: how can use a setter?

Comment: please provide context, e.g. block of codes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer this question:

Change this code:

```
System.out.println("Enter id before change : ");
String id = in.next();
for (Member m : member) {
    if (id.equals(m.getId())) {
        System.out.println(m.toString());
    }
}
System.out.println("Enter id after change : ");
String id2 = in.next();
System.out.println("program exit");
```

to:

```
System.out.println("Enter id before change : ");
String id = in.next();
for (Member m : member) {
    if (id.equals(m.getId())) {
        System.out.println(m.toString());
        System.out.println("Enter id after change : ");
        String id2 = in.next();
        m.setId(id2);
    }
}
System.out.println("program exit");
```

But I would suggest you to use HashMap instead of Array for Members in main() method, to avoid iterating multiple times. I don't know what this code is meant to do to suggest further optimizations.